# Returning a value of a key in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, return, key

I'm new to JS, and am curious on how to return a value of the key **name** in the property *name: "Eric"*. Here is the problem: *We are going to complete a function that takes in an object and a string (will refer to a key in the object). The function should return the value of the property located within the object at the given string key.* And here is my code:

```
function returnAValue(obj, key) {
  name: "Eric"
return name
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, and from what I understand it's asking me to put a string ("Eric") into the function *returnAValue* and the have it with a key ("name"). Then, return the value ("Eric") of the property ("name: "Eric"").

Thanks!

Comment: The homework problem you have is likely to be able to call the function with  `returnAValue({ name: 'Eric' }, 'name')` and get back `'Eric'`

Comment: This is not a correct syntax in JavaScript.

Comment: `(o,k) => o[k]`